# pandas to_sql(): is the operation atomic or not

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

i want to insert a pandas DataFrame into an existing mysql db in "append" mode like :

```py
df.to_sql(db, conn, if_exists='append')
```

is the above operation itself atomic or not?
if not, how can i make it atomic?
from the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), it has following:

```
chunksize : int, optional 
Rows will be written in batches of this size at a time. By default, all rows will be written at once.
```

Is it safe to assume that it's atomic because of the statement above"written at once"?

Comment: What do you mean by "atomic"? The `insert` itself will be atomic yes. I don't really understand your question.... Pandas relies SQLAlchemy for querying into MySQL. Maybe you mean that you should enclose your periodic inserts in a transaction, so that either all or none are executed? Please clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @Irnzcig: thanks for your comments, i mean the "to_sql" statement itself, so from your comments, it's atomic?

Comment: Yes. Take a look to [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html), you can control it using `chunksize`. Since in your example you put it to `None`, all rows are written at once. Of course it will depend on implementation for the ddbb engine but for MySQL it should be ok.

Comment: @Irnzcig:thanks, just curious, why the doc doesn't highlight that the operation is atomic or not rather than some general comments like "write at once", there is some gap in between, right:)

Comment: Well it depends on the ddbb engine and `pandas` relies on `SQLAlchemy`. In some cases it will be atomic, but in some others it won't. I'll post an answer to explain why I think it is atomic, but I haven't tested it (and I'm not going to right now)... Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks @Irnzig, looking forward to your detailed answer:)

Comment: I will try to build a test during the weekend and I'll let you know. Cheers.

Comment: hi @Irnzig,did you do your test?

Comment: Hey! Sorry still did not have the time... Your question is easily reproducible, I just need a database installed, which is something that I don't have at home right now. Cheers